# How to select a QTableWidget cell containing a button

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qtablewidget

I have a question regarding QTableWidget at PyQt4. Say I have a QTableWidget, where I want to have an event connected to a cell click using:

```
table.cellClicked.connect(cellClick)
```

then, *cellClick* function does its job. The thing is: some cells contain a button, like so (coordinates 0,0 as an example):

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton()
table.setCellWidget(0,0, button)
```

Now comes my problem. The presence of the button in a cell (which takes up the entire cell space) completely disables the *cellClicked* - the cell doesn't get clicked, the action can't be detected. But I do want my button to fill the cell.

So, in short, my question is - how can I select (click) a QTableWidget cell when there's a button inside it?

Answer (score 12):

The simple answer would seem to be:

```
    button.clicked.connect(cellClick)
```

But then how would you know the row/column of the cell that was clicked? So the next iteration might be:

```
    button = QPushButton()
    table.setCellWidget(row, column, button)
    button.clicked.connect(
        lambda *args, row=row, column=column: cellClick(row, column))
```

Which is okay if the table is static. But what if the rows and columns can be rearranged? The row/column cached in the button's `clicked` handler could be invalidated in that case. So the next iteration might be:

```
   index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(table.model().index(row, column))
   button.clicked.connect(
        lambda *args, index=index: cellClick(index.row(), index.column()))
```

(NB: you can connect other slots to the button's `clicked` signal, but the order they will be invoked in is undefined)

Comment: Very good answer, covering all the range of the subject. Thanks for your time and effort.